# How to pin point location in google map in XCode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, google-maps, mkmapview

Hey guys,
I'm building an iPhone app for my company and in one of the sections I want to create a tab bar item where it pin point the location of my company. So far I built a basic map view, but I haven't figured what would the code be for pin pointing the location of my company. hope someone can help, thanks

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try investigating MapCallouts from Apple Sample Code?

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MapCallouts/Introduction/Intro.html