# Google maps pin

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, ios6

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this in google maps (not iphone maps)? with arrow, when I click it goes to another view

thank you

Comment: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067817/how-to-pin-point-location-in-google-map-in-xcode?rq=1) or [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442559/put-pin-on-google-map?rq=1)

Comment: Are you talking about the Google Maps SDK or Google Maps web site?

Comment: @gaige He is acting about Google Map SDK